# Ruby: How to add value to list and then combine into string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have a list where I keep adding elements depending on some condition and after all the processing I want to combine all the elements in the list separated by comma. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What have your tried so far and what's the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: i have got the asnwer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = []

# Push 'some value' into the array if the condition is met
a << 'some value' if some_condition
a << 'another value' if some_condition

# a.join will return a string containing all elements separated with the argument
a.join(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can extend `Array` class with method like this:

```
class Array
  def conditional_add(value, condition)
    self << value if condition
    self.join(",")
  end
end
```